# Response header have cookie but not store in browser , Next js 13 App dir / go , gin server

Tags: go, cookies, next.js13, go-gin

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
*
Content-Length:
58
Content-Type:
application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:
Sun, 22 Oct 2023 03:36:23 GMT
Set-Cookie:
jwt_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE3MDMxMjk3NzZ9.HdKCrf2f_tE-1xTInEWvl-8Txx-AxxWIHKnCR1k7R7k; Path=/; Domain=localhost; Max-Age=31536000; Secure; SameSite=None
```

I test it in Postman it work fine , but in browser never get store in cookie

Comment: It is unclear what URL you use. But if `Domain` does not match it, the cookie will not be stored. Your current setting would the cookie be available for `localhost` and `*.localhost`, but only if the original URL matches this. Note that 127.0.0.1 is not the same as localhost regarding from the perspective of the domain match. Since it is unlikely that you have `*.localhost` subdomains it would be better just to remote the domain attribute .

Comment: Domain cookie on localhost is problematic. Secure cookies on localhost require TLS on localhost.

Comment: Browsers silently reject attempts by insecure Web origins (such as `http://localhost:8080`) to create a cookie marked `Secure`. Besides, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is not compatible with credentialed access; if the response contains that header (name + value), the browser will refuse to set your cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was also facing this issue with Next.js and gin server. So there are a couple of things that needs to be checked, make sure your CORS policy is okay, and also your client is sending right request, besides that sometime Chrome does not store cookie for localhost, please also check it with Firefox. This setup was working for me.

- My next js frontend is running on http://localhost:3000/
- My goalng gin backend is running on http://localhost:8080/

Now on my backend I had this CORS policy for localhost development (you should update it for production)

```
router.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        AllowOrigins:           []string{"http://localhost:3000"},
        AllowMethods:           []string{"*"},
        AllowHeaders:           []string{"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,Accept", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"},
        AllowCredentials:       true,
        AllowWildcard:          true,
        AllowBrowserExtensions: true,
        AllowWebSockets:        true,
        AllowFiles:             true,
    }))
```

Also I am using this to set cookie

```
    ctx.SetSameSite(http.SameSiteLaxMode)
    ctx.SetCookie("refresh-token", rToken, rExp, "/", "localhost", false, true)
```

And on my Next.js fetch client I was including credentials

```
   const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/v1/auth/login`, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username,
                    password
                }),
                credentials: 'include',
            });
```